# Undo Selection with UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

When a user taps on a `UISegmentedControl` and changes which segment is selected, I want to perform some validation.  If the validation fails, I want to 'undo' their selection, and re-select the item that they previously had selected.

What's the easiest way to do this?  I think I need something like

```
- (BOOL) segment:(UISegmentedControl *)seg shouldSelectSegmentAtIndex:(NSInteger)newIndex`
```

but I was looking at the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html), but I didn't see anything like that - really I didn't see anything with `will` in it at all.  Will I have to create a category or subclass to do this, or am I just missing it?

I suppose I could add an ivar that holds the selected segment index after it has been validated, and then call `[mySegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:myIvar];` if validation fails, or `myIvar = [mySegmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex];` when it passes, but that feels a little messier.  It's also a bit of a pain if I have a lot of segmented controls on the same screen.  I believe if I do create my own subclass, I'll have to do something like this though.

EDIT:
Other programming languages I've used have natively supported an 'undo' feature, without the programmer having to implement the undo on his own.  I'm looking to see if anyone is aware of something like that for Objective-C.  If it does not exist, does anyone know of a better way to implement it other than the ivar method I described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there really is an elegant way to do that without subclassing. But since there are no subclassing notes on `UISegmentedControl`, that could be an option. Override `setSelectedSegmentIndex`, where you check through delegation whether that index should be selected. If it should, call `super`'s implementation. If not, just do nothing.

This does assume that there are no internal methods that mess things up (and which you can't override).

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure what you are asking, but if I understand correctly I do believe this would do the trick:

```
[mySegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventChanged];

- (void)segmentChanged:(id)sender
{
     if (myIvar != validated){
          [mySegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:defaultSegment];
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is pretty close to what I'm looking for, I'm just looking for a way to do it that is maybe a little bit more elegant.  I edited my OP to try to make it clearer what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you looked into NSUndoManager?

Comment: I have not, I'll read up on it some [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  From a first glance, this could be what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think `NSUndoManager` is what I'm looking for.  If you want to edit your answer to show an example of using it, I'll upvote and accept.